# Pythonnet missing AddReference method

Tags: python-3.x, python.net

On Win10 1709 x64 PC, installed Python 3.7.4 64-bit and pythonnet-2.4.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl. Confirmed clr.pyd and Python.Runtime.dll exist in:

> C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\

Placed My.Assembly.dll in:

> C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs\

This script fails:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("My.Assembly")
```

with error:

> AttributeError: module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'

When I remove the 2nd line, import clr succeeds, so it is finding clr.pyd.

Here are my currently-installed packages:

astroid==2.0.4
bottle==0.12.13
certifi==2018.10.15
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.3.9
conan==1.9.1
deprecation==2.0.6
distro==1.1.0
fasteners==0.14.1
future==0.16.0
idna==2.7
isort==4.3.4
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
mccabe==0.6.1
monotonic==1.5
node-semver==0.2.0
packaging==18.0
patch==1.16
pluginbase==0.7
Pygments==2.2.0
PyJWT==1.6.4
pylint==2.1.1
pyparsing==2.3.0
pythonnet==2.4.0
PyYAML==3.13
requests==2.20.1
six==1.11.0
tqdm==4.28.1
urllib3==1.24.1
wrapt==1.10.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a script named clr.py in my scripts folder :(  Deleted it and all is good now.

Answer (score 2):

There is possibly a naming conflict with the [clr](https://pypi.org/project/clr/) string styling package, which imports from `Lib\site-packages\clr\style_builder.py` and contains no `AddReference()` method.

The correct [clr](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/src/runtime/resources/clr.py) module source code via the `pythonnet` package looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpA76.png).

Try `pip install pythonnet` in a fresh environment to be sure there is no package conflict, then retry:

`import clr` 
`clr.AddReference()`

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for the reply. I didn't have that package installed. I updated my post to include the ones I do have.

Answer (score 0):

To know which clr you are currently having, you can use the module inspect

```
import inspect
print(inspect.getmodule(clr))
```

If it returns the path described above then it's not the good one.
In my case, the expected clr returns

```
 <module 'clr' from 'unknown'>
```

Also dir(clr) display what functions are available.
The expected one returns

```
['AddReference',
 'FindAssembly',
 'GetClrType',
 'ListAssemblies',
 '__class__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__spec__',
 '__version__',
 '_add_pending_namespaces',
 '_available_namespaces',
 '_extras',
 '_load_clr_module',
 'clrmethod',
 'clrproperty',
 'getPreload',
 'loader',
 'setPreload']
```

In my case, the import was working fine the first time, but not after a second run, when the module were reloaded.
I only observed that in spyder IDE, so I just moved to VisualStudio code, or even to simply running the script via a command line and that was fine.

You can also deactivate the user module reloader (UMR) option in spyder (Tools > Preferences > Python interpreter > untick Enable UMR), but it might have some side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this file： Python311\Lib\site-packages\clr.py ，Actual measurement can solve problems

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).